# Proclarity View Seems to be Out of Synch With the Associated Data Cube

Tags: mdx, data-cube, proclarity

My boss just handed me a task that neither he nor I have any experience in, nor do we have any strategies on how to approach it. The problem involves Proclarity and a Data Cube, neither of which are familiar to me at all. I'll do my best to provide pertinent information, and I'll be happy to provide more information upon request.

Here's the rundown- Our financial reporting department submitted a work ticket claiming that when they set up a view in Proclarity to show the sales person assigned to a specific customer they get a result set containing **all sales people** in the company, rather than the **single sales person assigned to the customer**. They've told us that this hasn't always happened- it's a new development.

Like I said before- I really don't know how to even begin approaching this problem. I'd never even heard of MDX before today. I went to MSDN and read a bit about basic MDX queries and looked at some questions here on StackOverflow. But I'm still completely clueless as to how to go about troubleshooting this problem. I don't really expect anyone to hand me an answer right off the bat, but hopefully somone can at least get me pointed in the right general direction.

For what it's worth, He's a copy of the MDX query, as generated by Proclarity's MDX editor:

```
SELECT {  } ON COLUMNS , 

{ [Customer].[Cust ID].&[WALM1000] } * { [Sales Person].[Sper Name].[All].CHILDREN } ON ROWS   

FROM [Basic Research Cube]  

WHERE ( [Measures].[Gross Sales] ) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE, CELL_ORDINAL, ACTION_TYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

The * operator is used to do the cartesien product of 2 sets. As a consequence the result of your query will contains rows with empty cells. You can remove these lines.

You can add `NON EMPTY` at the beginning of the axis expression:

```
SELECT { [Measures].[Gross Sales] } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY { [Customer].[Cust ID].&[WALM1000] } * { [Sales Person].[Sper Name].[All].CHILDREN } ON ROWS
FROM [Basic Research Cube]
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE, CELL_ORDINAL, ACTION_TYPE
```

If you want to learn Mdx, I advise you to read one of the books listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963/how-to-learn-mdx).

In the chpater 5 of this [document](http://extras.springer.com/2006/978-1-84628-174-7/Documentation/GettingStartedGuide.pdf) you can find how to remove the empty rows from the UI.